# A very simple query - Loading plain old javascript file with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, commonjs

Should be quite a common question for a webpack newbie but unfortunately couldn't find a solution -

My project uses webpack. I need to use a library but it needs to be used as the old way of adding script tag like

```
<script src="//messaging-public.realtime.co/js/2.1.0/ortc.js"></script>
```

However I am looking for some way through webpack (a loader or in some other way) such that I can use it like

`import ortc from "realtime-framework"`

or

```
import * as ortc from "realtime-framework"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either:

1. Install it from a package manager like `npm`;
2. Download the file locally and import it;
3. Or include it the normal way with a script tag, making sure it is included before your script.

Comment: 1 and 2 (of course)
3 - I don't want to put in index.html, etc file. I would like the non-commonjs script file to get bundled like other scripts

Comment: @NitinAgarwal There are not any other options as far as I am aware of. You may be able to find a webpack loader than can load from http.